# What are the benefits of defeating a boss again in the dream world?

Tags: hollow-knight

After i got the mantis claw ability i decided to inspect the crying/mourning in the room after the false knight fight and saw the dead maggot surrounded by his friends.
When dreamnailing it i was lead to another false knight fight but i decided to not do it yet. Is there a benefit to defeating them again? Do they get revived?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few different bosses have dream versions that can be challenged using the dream nail. These dream bosses are harder versions of the corresponding regular bosses, and the reward for defeating them is a relatively **large amount of the essence** that the Moth Seer asks for. The wiki has [more information about dream bosses (spoiler warning)](https://hollowknight.wiki/w/Category:Bosses_(Hollow_Knight)#Dream_Bosses).

Two dream bosses

> Grey Prince Zote and the White Defender

can be defeated multiple times in increasingly difficult battles, but only the first win has the dream essence reward, and the other dream bosses can only be defeated once.

Comment: Repeated defeats of Grey Prince Zote (each victory up to 4th) and White Defender (after 5th) lead to extra story-related events/interactions; no "material rewards" though.